# Login Chat server using XMPP protocol which has different result on Eclipse and Jmeter

Tags: java, xmpp, jmeter, smack

Writing code login to Chat server (Xmpp protocol) on Eclipse as below

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;

public class TestClass {


     public void login1(String chatHost, int chatPort, String chatService, String username, String password) throws XMPPException
        {
            ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(chatHost, chatPort,chatService);
            XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
            SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);
            config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
            config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.enabled);

            config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);

            try{
                connection.connect();
                connection.login(username, password);
            }catch (XMPPException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //connection.disconnect();
        }
}
```

And here the result on Debugger mode after running:

```
1. SENT
<stream:stream to="chat" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" version="1.0">
<starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
<stream:stream to="chat" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" version="1.0">
<auth mechanism="PLAIN" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">dGVzdF9xYzIAdGVzdF9xYzIAMTIzNDU2</auth>
<stream:stream to="chat" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" version="1.0">
<iq id="H6Hv1-0" type="set"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><resource>Smack</resource></bind></iq>
<iq id="H6Hv1-1" type="set"><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/></iq>
<iq id="H6Hv1-2" type="get"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"></query></iq>
<presence id="H6Hv1-3"></presence>

2. RECEIVE
<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='2870319385' from='chat' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>
<stream:features><starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/><mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanisms><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/' ver='fhdjfhdjfhdjfdhjfhdjfdh='/><register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/></stream:features>
<proceed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>
<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='1869860261' from='chat' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>
<stream:features><mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanisms><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/' ver='fhdjfhdjfhdjfdhjfhdjfdh='/><register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/></stream:features>
<success xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'/>
<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='2794025275' from='chat' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>
<stream:features><bind xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind'/><session xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session'/><sm xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:2'/><sm xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/' ver='fhdjfhdjfhdjfdhjfhdjfdh='/><register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/></stream:features>
<iq id='H6Hv1-0' type='result'><bind xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind'><jid>test1@chat/Smack</jid></bind></iq>
<iq type='result' id='H6Hv1-1'/>
<iq from='test1@chat' to='test1@chat/Smack' id='H6Hv1-2' type='result'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'/></iq>
<presence from='test1@chat/Smack' to='test1@chat/Smack' id='H6Hv1-3'/>


3. INTERPRETED:
<success xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"></success>
<iq id="H6Hv1-0" type="result"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><jid>test_qc2@chat/Smack</jid></bind></iq>
<iq id="H6Hv1-1" type="result"></iq>
<iq id="H6Hv1-2" to="test1@chat/Smack" from="test1@chat" type="result"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"></query></iq>
<presence id="H6Hv1-3" to="test1@chat/Smack" from="test1@chat/Smack"></presence>
```

Export the code program in Eclipse to jar file and put to /lib/ext of Jmeter, then create a BeanShell sampler, writing the script:

```
import test.TestClass; // import our package.java file (same as import statement in IDE)


TestClass t = new TestClass(); // instantiate new TestClass
t.login1(vars.get("HOST"), Integer.parseInt(vars.get("PORT")), vars.get("SERVICE"), vars.get("username"), vars.get("password"));
// store returned method value in squaredResult variable. Convert param to int since squareIt expects int
```

Then run Jmeter. But the result on Debugger-Jmeter returns different Eclipse.

```
1. SENT
<stream:stream to="chat" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" version="1.0">
<starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
<stream:stream to="chat" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" version="1.0">
<auth mechanism="PLAIN" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">dGVzdF9xYzEAdGVzdF9xYzEAMTIzNDU2</auth>
<stream:stream to="chat" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" version="1.0">
<iq id="nJW60-0" type="set"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><resource>Smack</resource></bind></iq>

2. RECEIVE
<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='47494213' from='chat' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>
<stream:features><starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/><mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanisms><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/' ver='kgfkgjfkgjfkgjfkgjfkg'/><register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/></stream:features>
<proceed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>
<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='4171650187' from='chat' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>
<stream:features><mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanisms><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/' ver='kgfkgjfkgjfkgjfkgjfkg'/><register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/></stream:features>
<success xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'/>
<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='4026199172' from='chat' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>
<stream:features><bind xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind'/><session xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session'/><sm xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:2'/><sm xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/' ver='kgfkgjfkgjfkgjfkgjfkg'/><register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/></stream:features>
<iq id='nJW60-0' type='result'><bind xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind'><jid>test1@chat/Smack</jid></bind></iq>


3. INTERPRETED:
<iq id="nJW60-0" type="result"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><jid>test1@chat/Smack</jid></bind></iq>
```

I wonder why SENT/RECEVICE/INterpreter message on Jmeter-Debugger is not enough ? and how to get full content message as in Eclipse for Jmeter ?

And please help me edit my code if has problem.

Thanks in advance.